# Return array with values that have types mapped from rest parameter

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I want to create React hook to get user settings.
Here is a simplified example of that:

```js
import React from "react";

interface UserSettings
{
    SHOW_TIME_IN_HEADER: boolean;
    GRID_SIZE: number;
}

const USER_SETTINGS: UserSettings = {
    SHOW_TIME_IN_HEADER: true,
    GRID_SIZE: 8,
};

export const useUserSetting = <S extends keyof UserSettings>(...setting: S[]): UserSettings[S][] =>
{
    return setting.map(s => USER_SETTINGS[s]);
};

export const Component = () =>
{
    const [
        showTime, // Should be boolean but it is number | boolean
        gridSize // Should be number but it is number | boolean
    ] = useUserSetting("SHOW_TIME_IN_HEADER", "GRID_SIZE");

    return (
        <div>
            {"..."}
        </div>
    );
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgFUBnegZSRhhoHM25AN7kAkJwASAeQDqAfQAqASQCyAUXnKAcvMnqAggBF1CAFxwARhAgAbVNQpiA4gmVH5nZQC11F6gCuIJb0FAC%20lGgQ1GzwLJymnuqKKtrOnBbsXDx81IJwALxwonClcFJySmqaOnqGJuZwMFABSAA05GVwru6ePn5wABwdYRTkSAAekLBwUTHwARxZUNy8AoVwADyccJN01AAmbHAA1kgAnhCYrBwrOQJsAHwAFAB07xxreRacANoAugBKTK3Va5QS-Tj-AGFR4icREGABKDUOCfcGvEAoMDPY4FR6sBIIJIpHTpX5sIHhMaTabwOaxOAAYVwkGoSFoG2egNh8LEDPgv3EYjYAAsIAB3RSgdpwAD0cvK4oCtgOVmY1jsDisAXgwD1x0CwXocAAPlYbPYUNRhfwoMADpxgAAvZgKpUQFVqkJwI0hKA6vUG31Bf1mi1a63if4bRZIZZggTPfAVBQqDRaXT6YymfBtAg9DxeXz4QFjMSI5Go57CzYHYAANzhYhbwnw71e%20AiLc2cvrTfEZfIoyAA)

I would like the hook to return an array with settings values that are of its corresponding type. In this example the types of the returned values are both `number | boolean` but only one of them should be type `number` or `boolean`.

Is that even possible? And how would that method be named? My biggest problem right now is to find the correct words for this problem to be able to search for it.

If someone knows the answer to my problem or just knows the words to describe my problem, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the return type of `useUserSetting` to be a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays). This means the `setting` rest parameter shouldn't be typed as `S[]`, since that's just an array type which will forget about ordering.  Instead, have the generic type parameter `S` itself be an array type, and give `setting` the type `S`. This will allow the compiler to infer a tuple type for `S`.

Here's the typing I'd recommend:

```
export const useUserSetting = <S extends Array<keyof UserSettings>>(
    ...setting: S): {
        [I in keyof S]: UserSettings[Extract<S[I], keyof UserSettings>]
    } => {
    return setting.map(s => USER_SETTINGS[s]) as any; // need an assertion here
};
```

The return type maps over the numeric keys `I` of the `S` tuple, and produces `UserSettings[S[I]]`.  Unfortunately the compiler can't verify that `S[I]` will be a key of `UserSettings` (it erroneously thinks that perhaps `I` might be one of the non-numric keys of an array like `"push"` or `"pop"`), so I use the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to deal with it.  `Extract<S[I], keyof UserSettings>` means "take `S[I]` only only return the parts of it that are assignable to `keyof UserSettings`"; that is essentially a no-op, but it does convince the compiler to allow us to proceed.

Notice that the compiler also cannot verify that the implementation, `setting.map(s => USER_SETTNGS[s]`, is assignable to that mapped tuple type.  The [standard library's typings for `Array.prototype.map()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/bf977ed9189d2f795930366c1baa2cfcab123e1e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1349) only returns an `Array` and not a tuple, so any ordering information is lost.  In the above implementation I just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to `any` and move on.  Presumably you care more about the experience for the *callers* of `useUserSetting()` than the experience of the *implementer*, so let's check that out:

```
const [
    showTime, // boolean
    gridSize // number
] = useUserSetting("SHOW_TIME_IN_HEADER", "GRID_SIZE");

gridSize.toFixed(); // okay
```

Hooray!  The return type of `useUserSetting()` there is `[number, boolean]`, and therefore `gridSize` is known to be a `number` and can be treated as such (e.g., `gridSize.toFixed()` does not cause a compiler error).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgFUBnegZSRhhoHM2cAN7kAkJwASAeQDqAfQAqASQCyAUXnKAcvMnqAggBF1CAFxwARhAgAbVNQpiA4gmVH5nZQC11F6gCuIJb0FAC+lGgQ1GzwLJymnuqKKtrOnBbsXDx81IJwALwi4lJySmqaOnqGJuZwMFABSAA04q7unj5+cAAcrWEU5EgAHpCwcFEx8AEcWVDcvAKFcAA8nHAjdNQAJkIGUFAoAJ4rANZIRxCYrBzzOQJsAHyPABTiAHSfHIt5FpwAlBZRGIxABtZRwGhwc6Xa6cAC6mVuC1yglB6mGDXQMDW4PhzWhFyuN2yP0Ej3h4jChUexTERBgASg1Dg31R7xAKDALyEBVp8USCRSOnSoLY8P+cBQQhQ1COpDgAHpFXBqEgkNspSzpbc+NE4AALehIcgDSgjMbwSaxOAAYVwkDVtGWL0lfLp1vgoPEYjYBogAHdFKAWkqVdY7A4ffwoMBtpxgAAvZjK1VBEJQcTw5YzJBzFECF74UoKFQaLS6fTGUz4An4doeLy+fD-QZiGNxhPJ94wCAAMWAww1roVqYgp2OlHpPCZLLeIJW22AADdHj6xMJ8J93vgIgvFUvV+JW6bSEA)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I want to do! Thank you for the solution and also for the explanation and links, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, if it currently not possible. [this is the best I can come up with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgFUBnegZSRhhoHM25AN7kAkJwASAeQDqAfQAqASQCyAUXnKAcvMnqAggBF1CAFxwARhAgAbVNQpiA4gmVH5nZQC11F6gCuIJb0FAC%20lGgQ1GzwLJymnuqKKtrOnBbsXDx81IJwALxwonClcFJySmqaOnqGJuZwMFABSAA05GVwru6ePn5wABwdYRTkSAAekLBwmAHUGMDRcAEcWVDcvAIAPJxwk3TUACZscADWSACeEJisHBs5AmwAfAAUbBacAJQWANrrm1ygl%20nAAuqDSHBxlNoFh5otlqskADHnldvsJocTucrjc7tktnk2G04AA1DFY04Xa63FGEwRvD7lElsACMFlJPzg-3ugKeINBJLpQLYv1J4Mh0OmcIWfERa15qP46IOSGOVNxtMV9JerwAdAaOPTPr9QVzhfywabiuIiDAAlBqHAjUC9SAUGB3oVnqwEggkikdOlfmwzeExpNpXAojF4ABhXCQahq%20BFV5fb0icQx2Lc8RiNgACwgAHdFKB2nAAPRV8rFgK2I5WZjWOwOKwBeDALunQLBehwAA%20Vhs9hQ1Hz-CgwCOnGAAC9mDW6xAG02QnA%20yEoB2uz3N0Ft0OR23x%20JQYUVgqCUDXvgKgoVBotLp9MZTPgSfgeh4vL58F8YxiHaDpOq8%20bbEcwAAG7PPmYjCPgBp6vgERiGI2xVlBsHiIB5CjEAA)